# when i use aggregate match before and after group in mongodb, all result will appear (before + after) match filter?

Tags: mongodb

Here is my mongo query:

I have order collection. I have to count those order which customer first-time order comes from affillite.

```
     db.Orders.aggregate([
     {  $match:{ "Status": { $ne: "PaymentFailed" } }},

    {

      "$group": {
        _id: "$UserId",
        count: {$sum: 1},
        Order: {
          $first: {
            OrderNumber: "$OrderNumber",
            CreatedOn:"$CreatedOn",
            TrackingId:"$Tracking.AffiliateId"
          }
        }
      },
      "$match":{ "Order.TrackingId": { $not: { $type: 10 } }, "Order.TrackingId": { $exists: true  } }
    },

  ])
```

Comment: You'll likely want to add a $sort if you're relying on $first to get a particular item